# Integrating Apache Zeppelin notebook into a web application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I would like to integrate Apache Zeppelin notebooks into another web application that has existing integration with Apache Spark.

What is the best way of doing this? I am considering two possibilities:

- Render notebooks and paragraphs myself using the Zeppeling REST API: Zeppelin provides a REST API for interacting with notebooks and paragraphs. This is great, but I feel I would have to duplicate a lot of front-end from Zeppelin when building my own UI to render notebooks and paragraphs.
- Render an iframe showing Zeppelin's notebook, integrating on the Spark level: This re-uses Zeppelin's rendering of a notebook, at the cost of an iframe.

I hope my intentions are clear. I would prefer the first option if there is a simple way of rendering a Zeppelin notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Zeppelin design does not allow for easy integration into other systems, so the best approach is probably rendering an iframe to a notebook.

Alternatively, https://github.com/cloudera/livy can be used as a REST API for Spark, and a notebook interface (possibly forked from Zeppelin) can be created on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can create iframe or similar,You will get your required component by passing proper parameter

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/other_features/publishing_paragraphs.html

:/#/notebook/2B3QSZTKR/paragraph/...?asIframe" height="" width="" >